# Append HTML elements by PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to append my `head` tag with `script` tag(with some contents) in external `Html` file using `PHP` code.
But my `Html` is not updating or showing any errors.

### PHP Code:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtmlFile( 'myfolder/myIndex.html');
$headNode = $doc->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);

$scriptNode = $doc->createElement("script");
$headNode->appendChild($scriptNode);

echo $doc->saveXML();

?>
```

### Html File :

(A simple html pattern)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I have refered to the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) 
Couldn't figure out the problem still.

Comment: What did the echo statement show?

Comment: Works fine https://3v4l.org/AQOau

Comment: Are you perhaps under the impression that `$doc->saveXML()` would change the HTML file on the disk that you initially read the HTML code from …?

Comment: @KoalaYeung showing nothing.

Comment: @04FS if not by this way,Is there any other work around to update the html file on the disk

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtmlfile.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a very simple HTML file ( `simple.html` )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>A simple HTML Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Simple HTML</h1>
        <p>Well this is nice!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then using the following

```
$file='simple.html';


libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $file );
$errors = libxml_get_errors();
libxml_clear_errors();




$script=$dom->createElement('script');
$script->textContent='/* Hello World */';

/* use [] notation rather than ->item(0) */
$dom->getElementsByTagName('head')[0]->appendChild( $script );



printf('<pre>%s</pre>',htmlentities( $dom->saveHTML() ));

/* write changes back to the html file - ie: save */
$dom->saveHTMLFile( $file );
```

will yield ( for display )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A simple HTML Page</title>
    <script></script></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Simple HTML</h1>
        <p>Well this is nice!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: printf displaying html fine, but html file is not updating similarly

Comment: at the end you need to save the file once more.. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Good - glad it helped